# .htaccess remove all 1st level subdirectories from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've got several minisites which have all been redesigned.
I need to remove all sub directories though (there are litterally thousands so I can't list them), for example:

```
webdomain.com/old-directory/info.html
webdomain.com/another-directory/anotherpage.html
```

to:

```
webdomain.com/info.html
webdomain.com/anotherpage.html
```

Can I do this in `.htaccess`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all the 1st level subdirectories from all the links on your website(s).
2. Add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root to **redirect** links that are not under your control:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
   ```